# UDP Sockets Processing

Tags: java, sockets, processing

I am writing the server side of an UDP Socket in Processing and encountering a NullPointerException every time on the line `DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, 4096);`. The client side is a Python file. Here is the code for the server. The methods `setup()` and `draw()` are called through different Processing files.

```
import processing.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

//Server myServer;
DatagramSocket serverSocket;
byte[] receiveData;
InetAddress IPAddressList;
int portList = -1;

void setup(){
  try{
      DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(21567);
  }
  catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);
  }

   byte[] receiveData = new byte[4096];
}

void draw(){

  float P1,P2,P3;
  print ("hello");
  try{
     DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, 4096);
     serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
     String greeting = new String(receivePacket.getData());
     System.out.println("From Client: " + greeting);
     IPAddressList = receivePacket.getAddress();
     portList= receivePacket.getPort();
     P1 = Integer.valueOf(greeting);
     print(P1);
     print (greeting);
   }
   catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }

  for (int i=0;i<receiveData.length;i++){
    print(receiveData[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line where you pointed out the `NullPointerException` is very helpful.

The problem is that you initialized a *local variable* `receiveData` instead of the *field* `receiveData` in the outer scope.

To solution is to simply replace the line `byte[] receiveData = new byte[4096];` with `receiveData = new byte[4096];`.

In general, this is called name shadowing:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing
- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.3.1

Comment: After editing the code like you said, I get the `NullPointerException` on the next line now...`serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);`

Comment: Ah. Same problem with the variable `serverSocket`: don't declare it locally.

Comment: To reiterate explicitly, what you did is that within the `try` block you created the variables `serverSocket` and `receiveData`, which are **different** from the same-named variables `serverSocket` and `receiveData` created further above in the outer scope. This effect is called name shadowing.